# "Can't Expand Stack Segment By..." Problem With Recursive Function

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips

I've got a problem in MIPS with my recursive function. I've made a qsort function:

```
#a0--> int f (lower number)
#a1 --> int l (higher number)
#v0--> The return from the partition function (int p)
#
qsort:
            addi $sp, $sp, -12 #make room on stack for 3 registers.
            sw $ra, 8($sp) #save $ra on stack
            sw $a1, 4($sp) #save $a1(argument l) on stack
            sw $a0, 0($sp) #save $a0 (argument f) on stack
            move $t1, $a1
            slt $t0, $a0, $t1 #if f>=l then $t0=0
            bne $t0, $zero, L1 #if $t0 != 0 then jump to L1
            lw $ra, 8($sp)
            lw $a1, 4($sp)
            lw $a0, 0($sp)
            addi $sp, $sp, 12
            jr $ra

  L1:
            jal partition
            move $s1, $v0 #int p=partion (f, l)
            lw $a0, 0($sp) #pass the f to f argument qsort(f, p-1)
            addi $a1, $s1, -1 #pass p-1 to l argument of qsort
            jal qsort
            addi $a0, $s1, 1 #pass p+1 to f argument of qsort
            lw $a1, 4($sp) #pass l argument to l argument of qsort(p+1, l)
            jal qsort
```

And when i run the program in QtSpim, i take this error: "Can't Expand Stack Segment By 8 Bytes".
Do you have any ideas why?
Thank you.

My main:

```
main:       la $s0, array
                  li $a0, 0
                  li $a1, 9
                  jal partition
                  li $v0, 10 # Terminate program run
                  syscall # Exit
```

Comment: You probably get into endless recursion. Also, you forgot to end your function properly.

Comment: @Jester Yes, but why? What do you i mean i forgot to end my function properly?

Comment: You should single step the code to see why the recursion never ends. Compare what the cpu is doing to what you want it to do. As for the ending, the last line is a `jal qsort`. That will eventually return but you have no more code.

Comment: Where's your `main`?

Comment: @ErikEidt I just added.

Comment: @Jester  Why though?

Comment: Why what? For the recursion single step the code. You should know when you want the recursion to end, so check why the cpu is doing something else. For the ending `jal` is a subroutine call, its job is to return after executing the function.